# Android attach new data without smashing the old one with an adapter

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter

My problem is the next:

i have one way to bind data <-> View that is ... using an adapter, that simply inflates one specific layoyt and binds the column names to a ids in layout for each row in cursor (database cursor), this is whats the job of the adapter.

I have at time one listview with data (binded with this adapter) than used one cursor to get all items

But i add a new item, and i goes back to my old view and now the oldview must contain the new item, and i, the developer what i do is:

i go to db get the last one id. if the last one id is greater than the lastone in listview i return a cursor that contains the next elements, and now i wanna bind to the listview **WITHOUT** smashing the old values, but just adding using the same adapter to have a common way to bind the data to my view?

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right, all you need is to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of retrieving and adding new data from db manually. Or even use [this method of Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) instead to simplify.

Comment: how? i need provide more data. how can notifyDataSetChanged refreshes my content from database and put just the new one??? i am not understanding..

Comment: If you wanna know `how` then you probably should look through the `CursorAdapter` sources. If you want to refresh your adapter (assuming that your db, for example, has some new records), you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter or `startManagingCursor(yourCursor)` in `onCreate` of `Activity`.